# Group by and count mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, phpmyadmin

[image: How my table is organized]

**I need to count how many vehicleid there is for each day, or a group by day, counting the vehicles for that day ( The "metrictimestamp" field have the dates)**

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: i only know how to group by certain field, have no ideia how to count other field inside this group

Comment: you're almost there, you just need to add the count to the select clause, like `select metrictimestamp, count(vehicleid)` (you'd need to group by metrictimestamp)

Comment: like this: SELECT metrictimestamp,COUNT(vehicleid) FROM `data`?

Comment: yep, you'll need `group by  metrictimestamp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a straigh-forward aggregation query:

```
select date(metrictimestamp) metricdate, count(*) no_vehicles
from data
group by date(metrictimestamp)
order by metricdate
```

This assumes that `metrictimestamp` has a time component - so using `date()` removes it.

If you have rows where `vehicle_id` is `null`, use `count(vehicle_id)` instead of `count(*)`. If a given `vehicle_id` may appear more than once on a given day and you want to count it only once, use `count(distinct vehicle_id)`.